# Will overwriting `<-` cause me issues?

Tags: r

For a package I'm developing I want to overwrite `<-` on the global environment so that it prints some arguments. Having examined the help, it looks like I can't just assign it methods as I can `+`, `*` etc. I have the following function created at the moment:

```
`<-` = function(a,b){
  base::`<<-`(a,b)
  if (identical( parent.frame(n = 1) , globalenv() )){
    print('hello world')
  }
}
```

I need to use `<<-` rather than `<-` so that it goes to the correct environment, and I only want this to print something when working globally (to prevent a hideous number of messages).

My question is, is replacing `<-` with `<<-` in an inner function a bad idea? Is it likely to break any code? My feeling is that this should be relatively safe to do, but I'm not very clear on how the underlying c code R is calling interacts, so I wanted to check if this is likely to break something.

EDIT: in response to comments, to clarify what I want is a way to apply (probably just S3) methods to `<-` so that if I see a data frame or a list I can provide metadata to the console. However, I don't seem to see a way to just add methods to `<-` as you can for `+` and `*`. If someone has a better way to accomplish this than the above code I'm happy to hear it, although it would be useful to know if that code can actually cause issues (I'm wondering if it might cause performance issues although I'd hope not)

Comment: It can only sound very dangerous for anyone loading your package

Comment: Looks like instead of learning how to hold the shovel (I mean a real shovel not `<-`) you are modifying it and asking if it will chop your toes off by accident.

Comment: I think it would be good to take one step back, i.e. please clearly describe your problem, then we might have a better solution than masking `<-`.

Comment: By changing the expected behaviour of something as fundamental as `<-` you're going to potentially frustrate or anger any potential users of your package.

Comment: Hi, I understand the worries about this. This package is aimed at providing more informative log messages (and would probably only be loaded in batch mode). In particular, I would like it if as I make an object in R R then gives me information on that object. I considered making a wrapper function which does this but I think using that would be a pain. By associating this with assignment I can trigger the message exactly when I want it without the user having to do any more work.

Comment: If I could assign methods to `<-` I would prefer that greatly, but I don't know that that is possible.

Comment: So for instance I'd like ``<-.data.frame`` to add a message to the console saying "<object name> has n rows and m columns"

Comment: Terrible idea. Trying to change the meaning of the most fundamental and fastest operator in R isn't going to make your users happy. Not at all. No matter how good an idea you assume it is, it isn't. `i <- 1` won't benefit if you turn it from a couple-of-cycles safe operation into a thousands of cycles risky process. It's not only that the user's wokr will become a lot harder, they won't even know if things work or not.

Comment: And don't forget every other package out there. NONE of them expect assignment to be anything other than assignment. Modifying it will break *all* of them, resulting in unexpected behaviour, serious performance problems or worse. No parallelization can work if the *assignment* stops being a simple operation. `print('hello world')` already introduces a concurrency bottleneck

Comment: You could create your own infix operator such as `%=%` (I don't know if that specific one is already in use in standard packages). Those look somewhat awkward but if well-motivated are useful and can even become popular with users as the case of `%>%` shows. But -- I am not convinced that your intended application is well-motivated since I think that the console is a bit too verbose already.

Comment: @KieranMartin - The desired behavior already exists in the `str()` function, e.g. `str(data,list.len=0)` to suppress printing of column  vectors.